# Example on random graphs (Erdos-Renyi)

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

In class, we were given an example on random graphs, which works the following way:

Let $n \in \Bbb N, n \ge 1, V = \{1,...,n\}$ and $p = 1/2$. Let $C$ be a fixed cycle with length $3$ and $V(C) \subset V$. In $G(n,p)$ (the Erdos-Renyi space), we have

$$P(C \in G_{\omega}) = (1/2)^3.$$

Here, $G_{\omega}$ denotes a graph with vertices $V$ and edges $E = \{e: \omega_e = 1\}.$ $P$ is supposed to be the product measure. But aren't we missing the probability $q = 1/2$ here? The way I understand it, $P(C \in G_{\omega}) = (1/2)^3$ tells us that with a probability of $(1/2)^3$, the graph $G_{\omega}$ contains the desired cycle. But since we work with the product measure, shouldn't the probability look like $p^kq^{n-k}$?

Comment: No, $p^3q^{N-3}$ is the probability that the only edges open amongst the $N$ possible edges, are those in $C$, which is much more restrictive than the condition that the edges in $C$ are open.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! What do you mean by "open" though?

Comment: It is customary in the domain to call "open" every edge in $G(n,p)$ and "closed" every other edge of the complete graph.